# Style children based on their data attributes in TailwindCSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I have the following HTML

```html
<div>
    <p data-a="true"></p>
    <p data-a="false"></p>
    <p data-a="false"></p>
    <p data-a="false"></p>
</div>
```

The behaviour I am looking for, is that when the `p` element's `data-a` is true, a the font becomes bold.

I tried applying `[&>a]:data-[a="true"]:font-bold` to the parent `div` tag, but it tries to detect if the parent has data-a, and applied `font-bold` to all children when it is true. How do I change the "order of operations" here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single arbitrary variant, `[&>[data-a=true]>a]:` if you need it on the `<div>`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="[&>[data-a=true]>a]:font-bold">
  <p data-a="true">
    <a>Foo</a>
    <span>Bar</span>
  </p>
  <p data-a="false">
    <a>Foo</a>
    <span>Bar</span>
  </p>
</div>
```